# How to create own header structure in OMNET++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am using OMNET++ 5.5.1 with INET 4 framework.

In INET MAC protocols, each protocol has a fixed header structure. For example in XMAcHeader.msg, the MAC header defined as below:

```
class XMacHeaderBase extends FieldsChunk
{
    MacAddress srcAddr;
    MacAddress destAddr;
    XMacTypes type;
}
```

I want to extend this header structure where the MAC header will contain an additional bit along with the source address, destination address and type. I have to set/reset that bit before transmitting the packet to the receiver, so receiver can make some decision.

Can anyone suggest me how to create such header structure in OMNET++?

Thank you

Comment: Your question is to general to give an answer. Could you precise what MAC header do you want to extend (Ethernet, WiFi, etc.)? In OMNeT++ messages are defined in `*.msg` files. INET contains many examples of various MAC frames. Take a look at: `src/inet/linklayer/csmaca/CsmaCaMacHeader.msg`, `src/inet/linklayer/ethernet/EtherFrame.msg`.

Comment: Hi Jerzy, I want to extend XMAC header. In XMacHeader.msg, I can see the following:                                                                                                                 ```class XMacHeaderBase extends FieldsChunk
{
    MacAddress srcAddr;
    MacAddress destAddr;
    XMacTypes type;
}
``` If I want to add an additional bit in XMac header and set/reset that bit in .cc file, would you suggest the steps I need to follow? Thank you

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: Jerzy, would you answer my question please?